# Unable to map request from jqgrid to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to send form data from jqgrid to spring mvc controller but I am getting error as 
`HTTP Status 404-The requested resource is not available.`.

Below is my code.
`1)OverviewController.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="Overview")
public class OverviewController
{
    @Autowired
    OverviewService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="Order.spring",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getOrderView(ModelMap map,HttpSession session)
    {

        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("ViewOrders");
        modelAndView.addObject("ViewOrders", new OrderOverviewForm());
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="Order.spring",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody OrderOverviewResponse getOrderOverview(@RequestParam("AccId") Integer AccId
            ,@RequestParam("FromDate")Date FromDate
            ,@RequestParam("ToDate")Date ToDate
            ,@RequestParam("TransactionType") String TransactionType
            ,@RequestParam("_search") Boolean search
            ,@RequestParam(value="page", required=false) Integer page 
            ,@RequestParam(value="rows", required=false) Integer rows  
            ,@RequestParam(value="sidx", required=false) String sidx 
            ,@RequestParam(value="sord", required=false) String sord)
    {
        //          System.out.println(form);
        OrderOverviewForm form=new OrderOverviewForm(FromDate, ToDate, AccId, TransactionType);

        System.out.println("In overview POST");

        List<OrderOverviewData> datas=(List<OrderOverviewData>)service.getOrderOverview(form, 1);

        for (Iterator iterator = datas.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            OrderOverviewData orderOverviewData = (OrderOverviewData) iterator.next();  
            System.out.println(orderOverviewData);
        }
        OrderOverviewResponse response=new OrderOverviewResponse();

        response.setPage("1");
        response.setTotal("5");
        response.setRows(datas);
        response.setRecords(String.valueOf(datas.size()));

        return response;
    }


}
```

`2) ViewOrders.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></c:url>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></c:url>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></c:url>"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/resources/css/jquery-ui.min.css"></c:url>" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<c:url value="/resources/css/ui.jqgrid.css"></c:url>" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#target")
                .submit(

                        function(event) {
                            alert("H");
                            var data={};
                            data["AccId"]= $('#AccId').val();
                            data["FromDate"]= $('#FromDate').val();
                            data["ToDate"]= $('#ToDate').val();
                            data["TransactionType"]= $('#TransactionType').val();

                            $("#grid")
                                    .jqGrid(
                                            {
                                                url : '/Online Fund Trading/Overview/Order.spring',
                                                datatype : 'json',
                                                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },

                                                mtype : 'POST',
                                                colNames : [ 'Customer Id',
                                                        'Account Id',
                                                        'Order Id',
                                                        'Order Date',
                                                        'Order Amount',
                                                        'Order Units',
                                                        'Order Type', 'Fund Id' ],
                                                colModel : [ {
                                                    name : 'CusId',
                                                    index : 'CusId',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : false,
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        readonly : true,
                                                        size : 10
                                                    },
                                                    hidden : true
                                                }, {
                                                    name : 'AccId',
                                                    index : 'AccId',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : true,
                                                    editrules : {
                                                        required : true
                                                    },
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        size : 10
                                                    }
                                                }, {
                                                    name : 'OrdId',
                                                    index : 'OrdId',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : false,
                                                    editrules : {
                                                        required : true
                                                    },
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        size : 10
                                                    }
                                                }, {
                                                    name : 'OrdDate',
                                                    index : 'OrdDate',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : false,
                                                    editrules : {
                                                        required : true
                                                    },
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        size : 10
                                                    }
                                                }, {
                                                    name : 'OrdAmount',
                                                    index : 'OrdAmount',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : false,
                                                    editrules : {
                                                        required : true
                                                    },
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        size : 10
                                                    }
                                                }, {
                                                    name : 'OrdUnits',
                                                    index : 'OrdUnits',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : false,
                                                    editrules : {
                                                        required : true
                                                    },
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        size : 10
                                                    }
                                                }, {
                                                    name : 'OrdType',
                                                    index : 'OrdType',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : false,
                                                    editrules : {
                                                        required : true
                                                    },
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        size : 10
                                                    }
                                                }, {
                                                    name : 'FundId',
                                                    index : 'FundId',
                                                    width : 15,
                                                    editable : false,
                                                    editrules : {
                                                        required : true
                                                    },
                                                    editoptions : {
                                                        size : 10
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                ],
                                                postData : {
                                                    AccId : function() {
                                                        return $('#AccId')
                                                        .val();
                                                    },
                                                    FromDate : function() {
                                                        return $('#FromDate')
                                                                .val();
                                                    },
                                                    ToDate : function() {
                                                        return $('#FromDate')
                                                                .val();
                                                    },
                                                    TransactionType : function() {
                                                        return $('#FromDate')
                                                                .val();
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                rowNum : 20,
                                                rowList : [ 20, 40, 60 ],
                                                height : 200,
                                                autowidth : true,
                                                rownumbers : true,
                                                pager : '#pager',
                                                sortname : 'CusId',
                                                viewrecords : true,
                                                sortorder : "asc",
                                                caption : "Orders Overview",
                                                emptyrecords : "Empty records",
                                                loadonce : false,
                                                loadComplete : function() {
                                                },
                                                jsonReader : {
                                                    root : "rows",
                                                    page : "page",
                                                    total : "total",
                                                    records : "records",
                                                    repeatitems : false,
                                                    cell : "cell",
                                                    id : "id"
                                                }
                                            });

                            event.preventDefault();
                        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="target" enctype="application/json">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter AccId</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="AccId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>From Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="FromDate" /></td>
                <td>To Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="ToDate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Transaction Type</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="TransactionType" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" id="submit"
                    value="Get Orders"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <div id="jqgrid">
        <table id="grid"></table>
        <div id="pager"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
<br />
```

I have traced the content of request and response in mozilla.

```
Source
AccId=100&FromDate=&ToDate=&TransactionType=&_search=false&nd=1414507225627&rows=20&page=1&sidx=CusId&sord=asc
```

and Request and Response content,

```
Response Headersview source
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length  1041
Date    Tue, 28 Oct 2014 14:40:25 GMT


Request Headersview source
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:8080/Online_Fund_Trading/Overview/Order.spring
Content-Length  110
```

I have addded jackson jars also but still not getting what I am doing wrong.
Please help me in this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to post data from an edit in the jqgrid?

Comment: @AaronC No.What i want is user will enter search criteria in form.Then after submitting form jqgrid will get called and jqgrid will send request to spring controller along with form data.Then data returned by spring controller will be displayed in jqgrid.